# sudo chown /usr/bin/local not working permanently for homebrew upgrade

Tags: bash, homebrew, system-administration

i have tried `sudo chown $whoami /usr/local/bin` , after closing terminal and reopening terminal but it keeps getting permission denied, it doesn't fix it permanently.

```
shaunstanislaus@Master ~ $ brew upgrade
==> Upgrading 3 outdated packages, with result:
git 2.6.1, mysql 5.6.27, node 4.1.2
==> Upgrading git
Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/share/git-core
```

Comment: does anyone know how to resolve it permanently other than using `sudo chown $whoami /usr/local/bin` ?

Comment: Please compare the output of `whoami`, `echo $whoami` and `echo $(whoami)`

Comment: Are you using Sophos Anti Virus?

Comment: @bfontaine I'm having the same issues and yes, I'm using Sophos Anti Virus. I wonder if Sophos overwrite the permission after each reboot or something like that?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to chown (change ownership) of the `/usr/local/bin` `/usr/local/share`, `/usr/local/share/man` and `/usr/local/share/man/man1` directories.

To do this you do the following:

1. `whoami` - this will give you your current username
2. `sudo chown -R 'username' /usr/local/bin /usr/local/share /usr/local/share/man /usr/local/share/man/man1` (replace username with the username from step 1)

Now run `brew doctor`

You shouldn't see any issues.

Then run `brew upgrade`

If you are using Sophos Anti-Virus, the permissions will be reset each time Sophos updates in the background.

They are pursuing a fix for this and will be in place by mid Nov 2015 according to this forum post:

> https://community.sophos.com/products/free-antivirus-tools-for-desktops/f/17/t/10029

Comment: Or, just `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local` if you have nothing else in `/usr/local` that will be adversely effected.